# Assigning a value in an ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bunch of calendar controls on one of my pages. Originally I copied the sample code for the calendar control which ended up looking like this. (The relevant sections are the is-open and ng-click).

In the view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control show-text-cursor" disabled uib-datepicker-popup="{{ dateFormat }}" ng-model="myDate" is-open="openMyDate.opened"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openMyDate()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.openMyDate = function () {
    $scope.openMyDate.opened = true;
};
```

The problem is I end up with another function on my $scope for each calendar control I add (I'm up to 14). This seems way over the top to just set a boolean to true.

So I changed it to this.

The View:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control show-text-cursor" disabled uib-datepicker-popup="{{ dateFormat }}" ng-model="myDate" is-open="myDateIsOpen"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myDateIsOpen = true;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

The Controller:

```
//Initialization only
$scope.myDateIsOpen = false;
```

I wouldn't want to start unrolling functions directly into my ng-clicks, but since it's a single boolean assignment it seems so much cleaner this way. But I'm new to Angular and I'm wondering if having anything more than a function call in your ng-click can have a negative impact on performance?

Comment: A direct assignment could be a little more efficient for this case. Note that all ng-click events call scope.$apply() every time the event occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control show-text-cursor" disabled uib-datepicker-popup="{{ dateFormat }}" ng-model="myDate" is-open="myDateIsOpen"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myDateIsOpen = !myDateIsOpen;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run into issues with performance doing things like that.  There are other options, too, though.  You could also track these variables in a hash instead though... and call a single function with a key name... e.g.,

```
$scope.openMyDate = function(which_one) {
    $scope.dates_open[which_one] = true;
}
```

And the ng-click would simply be `ng-click="openMyDate('some_key_goes_here')`